# How to write this test case?

Tags: c#, mstest

I need to write this test method that checks that methods AMethod1 and AMethod2 return same results with same boolean parameters (AMethod1 was refactored to AMethod2)

How to implement all possible combinations of parameters when calling these methods? Of course, I can just copy paste 9 different combinations, but maybe there is a more elegant way?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void OriginalMethodAndOptimizedReturnSameResult()
    {
        // By supplying same set of parameters for both methods, 
        // the test should succeed if methods return same result

        var result1 = Program.AMethod1(false, false, false);
        var result2 = Program.AMethod2(false, false, false);

        Assert.AreEqual(result1, result2);
    }
}
```

And another question - how to fail this test if it runs longer than 10 seconds?

Comment: You could use reflection - but think about whether that's really worth it. It's going to be much more stable if you explicitly call the methods yourself. As for failing it after 10 seconds, you could implement a timer. But you should think about whether that's really appropriate for a unit test. A unit test should be repeatable in results. If the PC happens to be running slowly, you shouldn't fail the test when nothing else has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bit pattern of an iterated counter:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    var a = (i & 1) > 0;
    var b = (i & 2) > 0;
    var c = (i & 4) > 0;

    var result1 = Program.AMethod1(a, b, c);
    var result2 = Program.AMethod2(a, b, c);

    Assert.AreEqual(result1, result2);    
}
```

For the timeout mstest supports the [timeout argument @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.timeoutattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In VS2017 this seems to work, not sure which VS version are you using. Still verbose, but better than writing the 8 combinations:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(false, false, false)]
[DataRow(false, false, true)]
[DataRow(false, true, false)]
[DataRow(false, true, true)]
[DataRow(true, false, false)]
[DataRow(true, false, true)]
[DataRow(true, true, false)]
[DataRow(true, true, true)]
public void OriginalMethodAndOptimizedReturnSameResult(bool b1, bool b2, bool b3)
{
    // By supplying same set of parameters for both methods, 
    // the test should succeed if methods return same result

    var result1 = Program.AMethod1(b1, b2, b3);
    var result2 = Program.AMethod2(b1, b2, b3);

    Assert.AreEqual(result1, result2);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is "better". Now the code is less portable to another testing framework, and you have less control over the execution time, and you still end up with the same amount of code.

Comment: As the question was tagged as "mstest", I thought that the OP was interested only on that unit testing framework. I think that NUnit has a similar functionality with the `Values` attribute, maybe other frameworks have similar things too making possible to migrate this approach with some extra refactoring.